# Force boolean value in method call in JSP/EL

Tags: spring, jsp, el

I have a JSP-Page which contains the following

```
<td>${MyClass.mymethod(false)}</td>
```

and `MyClass` contains the following:

```
public static String mymethod(boolean param)
{
    //...
}

public static String mymethod(String param)
{
    //...
}
```

Now when I display the JSP-Page `mymethod(String param)` is called. How can I make the `false` a `boolean` value?

Comment: Would have expected `object.myMethod(false)`. By the way overloading cannot be done in EL, as far as I know.

Comment: my bad, changed it. Thats only a minimal example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does el support overloaded methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763619/does-el-support-overloaded-methods)

Answer (score 1):

Method names being put in a Map as keys.So there is no function overloading in el.or try giving different names for function in xml.